# Is it possible to turn a PHP XML Exporter into a Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I made a PHP Script with a form using mysql1 that can be used to export data from a database to an XML file. My question is can I use this as a Wordpress plugin?

The biggest issue im facing is that wordpress uses $wpdb to interact with a database where as I had been using PHP MySQL functions. Is there any way to convert a PHP a script to a wordpress plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
As you know, mysql_fetch_assoc() processes the results returned by mysql_query(). $wpdb class methods typically return results of a query to the wordpress database similar to what mysql_query() would do. $wpdb class methods do not process such results as mysql_fetch_assoc() would do, so there is no true equivalent.
```

What I usually do with the results from $wpdb queries that is similar to your example is:

foreach ($results as $row) {
    // Do code to process db results here.